# Is cloud database to store our data is available?

Tags: android, database, cloud

Is there any Database or Cloud which can be used to store our data?

Because i have an idea to create Android app which can use Cloud network to store data,photos,videos like that.

Sorry if my question is not sensible.

Thanks,
Shanmugam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) to store data in the cloud. AWS gives you the choice of a database or a raw storage. For DB, you can choose between [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) and [Relational Database Service (RDS)](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/). For raw storage, you can choose between [Simple Storage Service (S3)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and [Elastic Block Store (EBS)](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/).

Keep in mind that all these are paid services. There is a free tier, but it's volume and time-limited.

Comment: Disclaimer: I currently work for Amazon, but I don't work on AWS. Still, thought I should mention the fact.

Comment: Thanks Franci for ur suggestion and fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own server you could use an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and communicate with you android application using WCF web services.